# Differences between Github commands "Update Project" and "Pull" in Android Studio 3.3.1?

Tags: git, android-studio, github, command, pull

I use GitHub in my Android Studio 3.3.1 project.

There are similar icons next to both the menu items "Update Project..." and "Pull...".

What are different between `Update Project` and `Pull` commands in GitHub in Android Studio 3.3.1?

**VCS Menu**
[image: VCS]

**Update Project**
[image: Update Project]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For projects stored in one version control repository, there is no difference. If a project contains modules stored in different version control systems or repositories, Update Project will update all of them, and Git | Pull... will update only a single one.

Answer (score -2):

They are one and the same thing.
You can use either `Update Project`, `Pull` or the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Then the other are just options to select the branch and what you want to do with the current changes etc.

Comment: You can read various blogs on various options given in the Update Project. They correspond to various git commands.
eg. Merge => `git rebase --no-rebase`
Rebase => `git pull --rebase`